# Azure Backup Failure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have just received the following alert from our Azure Recovery Services Vault:

> Severity : Critical Alert : Backup failure Backup item(s) : XXXXXXX
>   Description : Snapshot operation failed due to VSS (Volume Shadow
>   Copy) service in bad state Recommended action(s) : Restart VSS (Volume
>   Shadow Copy) service and reboot VM. Time : 2017-09-07 02:36:01 GMT
>   Subscription id : XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXX Vault : XXXXXX

Has anyone come across this error? Can someone let me know what the process is in restarting the VSS (Volume Shadow Copy)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Error, this issue may caused by VSS. You can  take actions as the recommended actions to restart the VSS writes.

To achieve this, from an elevated command prompt, run :

```
vssadmin list writers
```

Output contains all VSS writers and their state. For every VSS writer whose state is not "[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot) Stable", restart VSS writer by running following commands from an elevated command prompt:

```
net stop serviceName 
net start serviceName
```

See more details about Azure VM backup troubleshoot, refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot).

See more details about Troubleshooting Volume Shadow Copy Problems,refer to this [article](https://support.intronis.com/Knowledge_Base/Backup_Agent/Troubleshooting_Volume_Shadow_Copy_Problems#The_VSS_Writer_Is_In_a_Bad_State).